# Recover from wrong PID 1 process

Tags: systemd, init

I’ve just run into a curious situation. To set up a new server, I logged into the OS preinstalled by the hosting provider and performed a pivot_root to a tmpfs so I could unmount the drives and reconfigure RAID. Having done that, I did another pivot_root to the newly created FS and ran `kill -TERM 1` (which is the same as systemctl daemon-reexec). This is where things went wrong as the new FS didn’t yet have the systemd package installed, and systemd ended up executing /bin/sh for some reason.

Now the system is in a strange state where a /bin/sh is running as PID 1, at least that’s what /proc/1/exe shows. Obviously rebooting fixes this, but in general, can such a situation be rectified without a reboot?

Comment: Maybe, if you can get the `sh` to `exec` something.